# "same hierarchical level" Error on HTTP (beta) API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Im trying to make a new HTTP API gateway but keep getting this error when I try to make routes with multiple parameters I want something like this

ANY /{param1}/entity/{param2}

ANY /{param1}/other/{param3}

Not sure why this keeps failing...

Comment: You have 3 parameterised routes. Do you know which two or one causes the conflict, or do you need all 3 to create the conflict?

Comment: @chughts Even if I do these 2 routes I get a conflict

ANY /{param1}/entity/{param2}

ANY /{param1}/other/{param3}

I get this error

The provided route key has a conflicting variable on the same hierarchical level as "ANY /parent/{param1}/entity/{param2}"

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue in serverless.yml when renaming a path parameter.

The workaround is to:

1. Take down the route (comment the said route in serverless.yml)
2. Deploy
3. Bring the route back with the new parameter (uncomment the said route)
4. Deploy again

For more reference check https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3785